# Rename Dataframe column names julia v1.0

Tags: dataframe, julia

In 0.6 I was using:

```
colnames = ["Date_Time","Date_index","Time_index"]
names!(data1_date_time_index.colindex, map(parse, colnames))
```

What is the syntax for v1.0 - right now .colindex is not found.

Per DataFrames docs:

```
rename!(data1_date_time_index, f => t for (f, t) =
   zip([:x1, :x1_1, :x1_2],     
       [:Date_Time, :Date_index, :Time_index]))
```

Comment: I have added a comment in my answer how you can get to `colindex` if you really need.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming `data1_date_time_index` is a `DataFrame` that has three columns use:

```
colnames = ["Date_Time","Date_index","Time_index"]
names!(data1_date_time_index, Symbol.(colnames))
```

I am not 100% sure if this is what you want, as your example was not fully reproducible (so if actually you needed something else can you please submit full code that can be run).

The problem with `data1_date_time_index.colindex` is that currently `.` is used to access columns of a `DataFrame` by their name (and not fields of `DataFrame` type). In general you are not recommended to use `colindex` as it is not part of exposed API and might change in the future. If you really need to reach it use `getfield(data_frame_name, :colindex)`.

**EDIT**

In DataFrames 0.20 you should write:

```
rename!(data1_date_time_index, Symbol.(colnames))
```

and in DataFrames 0.21 (which will be released before summer 2020) also passing strings directly will most probably be allowed like this:

```
rename!(data1_date_time_index, colnames)
```

(see [here](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/1926) for a related discussion)

Comment: Hey @Bogumil, you certainly know this already but  `names!()` has been deprecated now in favor of `rename!()`. Just a suggestion, but you might want to update your code above. Otherwise, this is a very helpful post as I needed to do something like this last night :).

Answer (score 6):

You can rename column through `select` also

For Ex:

```
df = DataFrame(col1 = 1:4, col2 = ["John", "James", "Finch", "May"])

│ Row │ col1  │ col2   │
│     │ Int64 │ String │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ John   │
│ 2   │ 2     │ James  │
│ 3   │ 3     │ Finch  │
│ 4   │ 4     │ May    │


select(df, "col1" => "Id", "col2" => "Name")

│ Row │ Id    │ Name   │
│     │ Int64 │ String │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ John   │
│ 2   │ 2     │ James  │
│ 3   │ 3     │ Finch  │
│ 4   │ 4     │ May    │
```

Comment: Using `select` is not practical, as you will need to provide all the column names, even in the case you want to change only one.  
I assume that is the reason for the `rename` function to exist.  

Additionally, in your example, you should use `select!` in order to modify the column names in place, or alternatively do 'df = select(df, "col1" => "Id", "col2" => "Name")`
as `select` always return a new `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 4):

Rename columns:

```
names!(df, [:c1,:c2,:c3]) #(all)

rename!(df, Dict(:oldCol => :newCol)) # (a selection)
```

(from: https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/useful-packages/dataframes )

Comment: `colnames` are strings so a conversion to `Symbol` is needed as I have answered in parallel.